# Fitting a function to data that exceeds the bounds due to large errors with matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am trying to fit (using matlab and the fitting toolbox) a function, which needs to be within certain bounds, to data points, which have rather large errors. Now the difficulty is, that the data (due to the large errors) often lies outside of the bounds and when I am restricting the fit with upper/lower bounds, the toolbox does use the value of the bound and does not give any confifence interval to the fitted value (obviously).

Here is a simple example of the code:

```
o = fitoptions('Method','NonlinearLeastSquares','Lower',[0],'Upper',[1]);
f = fittype(@(a,x) 0.5*(1-a*sin(x)));
fit(dataX,dataY,f,o);
```

The fitting paramater 'a' should be within 0 and 1, such that the fit is always between 0 and 1, too.

Since my data points are mostly negative (instead of close to 0) at the minimum, the unbounded fit gives me a value larger than 1, which I cannot use and if I set the upper bound to 1, it gives me exactly 1 (with the note: 'fixed at bound') but no confidence interval, which I need. The best would be, to get 1 with an increased confidence interval.

Is there a way to do that or maybe a more clever way to get the best value for 'a' given the restrictions?

Thanks for any help and/or suggestions!

Update:
Here is the data:

```
dataY=[0.65 0.25 -0.15 -0.4 -0.3 -0.13 0.27 0.65 0.94 0.96]
dataYerror=[0.49 0.48 0.48 0.47 0.49 0.48 0.48 0.49 0.50 0.47]
dataX  =[-0.50 0.13 0.77 1.41 2.05 2.68 3.32 3.96 4.59 5.23]
```

You see that the error is rather huge, and I think it should be possible to get a sin-function to lie above 0 and still agree (badly though) with the data and its error bars, or am I wrong?

Comment: It would be best if you could post or show your data.

Comment: What you mean is that the *parameters* need to be within certain bounds, correct?

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, I updated the question above.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the parameter 'a' needs to be within 0 and 1. That is why i put an upper limit to it. Thanks again.